# How to add custom property field to fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to add custom field in calendar below title, it is not getting displayed, any help?

[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMPJ6.png)

my code:

```
 <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
          

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                initialDate: '2021-08-17',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                events: [{

                    title: 'Event',
                    name: 'John',
                    start: '2021-08-17'
                }]

            });

            calendar.render();
            
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

In fullcalendar v3 working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   events: [{
                    title: 'My Event',
                    name: 'John',
                    start: '2021-08-12T12:00:00'
                }],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find('.fc-title').append(event.name);
    }
  });
});
```

in v5 eventRender was changed to eventDidMount, but when i'm trying use find method error appears.

Comment: Please show your current code as text, not pictures, and include your attempt to use eventDidMount, and also tell us exactly what the error message is. See also [ask] to confirm this guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Also, please provide a link to the documentation/library next time you post a question so that others immediatly know what technology you use.

Comment: @gerstams that information is already contained in the fullCalendar tag wiki - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fullcalendar/info

Comment: Okay, can you add your code here directly and not use a screenshot as suggested above? Then we can maybe to the next steps :-)

Comment: @gerstams you're mistaking me for the OP. And I already asked OP for that information in my first comment. :-)

Comment: @ADyson Wups :D

Comment: Do not mark questions as "solved" by editing the question, please. That's not how this site works, we aren't a forum. Instead, provide an Answer below. You're allowed to answer your own question - in fact it's encouraged, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . That way, your answer will be searchable by others. who can then upvote on it. But I'm glad you solved it - now please make your solution visible to others by putting it as an Answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'll give you some time to sort it out and then I'll remove the "solution" part of your question if necessary. (If you then need to copy it to an answer you can find it in the [revision history of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68805093/revisions) and copy it from there to an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I've used vanilla js and from event used extendedProps object which holds non-standart fields:

```
 events: [{

                    title: 'Event',
                    name: 'John',
                    start: '2021-08-17'
                }],

                eventDidMount: function(info) {
                    let name = document.createElement('div');
                    name.innerHTML=info.event.extendedProps.name;
                    document.querySelector('.fc-event-title-container').append(name);
                    
                }
```