# Fullcalendar: Show additional event data in list view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to display a month view which shows the time and title of events (and a popover showing the description when hovered). When I click the event, I show a listday view that shows all the events for that day. That all works fine and I have this working with this code:

```
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      start: 'dayGridMonth,listDay',
      center: 'title',
      end: 'prev,next'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2023-01-12',
    height: 'auto',
    dayMaxEvents: 3,
    moreLinkClick: 'listDay',
    eventClick: function(info){
      switchToListView(info)
    },
    eventColor: 'green',
    views: {
      listDay: {
        displayEventEnd: true
      }
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2023-01-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        description: 'My Description',
        start: '2023-01-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2023-01-12T12:30:00'
      },
```

and in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/tmhudg/pen/vYaxMpm?editors=001)

I'd like to show the description text for the event in addition to the title in the listday view and I can't figure out how to do this. I don't know whether I need to use an event hook or what. I just can't make my way through the docs and examples to see what to do.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You'd need the event render hooks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820157/5947043 probably helps you

Comment: Thank you @ADyson - that got me on the right track. I'm a bit of a newb to actually posting on SO so I'll post my answer separately.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with this use of eventDidMount.

```
    eventDidMount: function(info) {
      info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-event-title a').innerHTML += ` ${info.event.extendedProps.description}`
    },
```

Frankly, it feels a little weird that I need to go into the depths of the rendered HTML to adjust the output instead of changing what is going INTO the generated HTML but I guess that's just how it works (??)

Thanks to @ADyson for the push in the right direction.